# Bypassing URL verification

Tags: network, .net, url, uri

I'm dealing with a URL validation function that was made by the developer (instead of using trusted methods).

Here is a slightly modified version of the function:

```
    public static bool IsValidURL(string url) {
        string parsedurl = url.ToLower().Substring(8, url.IndexOf("/", 8) - 8);
        return url.StartsWith("https") && parsedurl.EndsWith("example.com");
    }
```

I need this function to return true for a URL string I supply and the URL must also be compatible with C#'s WebClient. My goal is to have it to connect to my own web server, any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will make it pass

`https://compromised.server.com?example.com/`

As long as `example.com/` is at the end of the URL and there are no other slashes, you can add as many query parameters as you want with other data.